# This operation cannot be performed while an auto-filled column is being resized

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
     Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1           
            Dim Query2 As String 
            Query2 = "Update blist SET quantity=(quantity-1) where quantity = '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' "
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query2, MysqlConn)
            SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
     **error**Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource**error**
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            MessageBox.Show("Success", "Informed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Next
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

i Cannot find a related problem into this in the internet what should i do? I am trying to deduct 1 quantity on the SqlDB when the user borrowed it. Yes! it execute the sql command but im having this this type of error.

bsource= Binding source
SDA = MysqlAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting

```
DatarGidView1.SuspendLayout
```

before the line where the error occurs, and

```
DataGridView1.ResumeLayout
```

after it, though I'm not sure if that would work

Comment: ah ok - Thanks - i'll delete it